# sublabel or supylabel or subxlabel

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a matplotlib function as suptitle but for xlabel and ylabel, something like supylabel, or matlab [suplabel](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7772-suplabel)

**EDIT:
I opened a ticket about it in matplotlib github:
[github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11147](http://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11147)**

Comment: No, there isn't. But it's sure possible to add a figure text at the desired position.

Comment: @tom  don't you think the keywords worth not closing the question?

Comment: The keywords are precisely the reason to close this as duplicate. This way any future search for some of the words provided in this question will direct the searcher to the actual answer.

Comment: Ok, so it is just closed and not deleted. So it means that I can give 1up to duplicated closed. ;)
Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11147

Comment: Maybe it's better to add the link to the issue in the duplicate target for people to find it.